# Android, Background

Tags: android, background

мне для кнопки нужен задний фон необычной формы. Я знаю что для создания background c закруглёнными углами мы используем команду corners, как сделать как на картинке? [image]

Comment: можно использовать Image Button и создавать программно форму кнопки

Answer (score 1):

Используй картинку *.9.png как фон.

```
android:background="@drawable/edit_background"
```

Картинку edit_background.9.png в drawable-hdpi.
Вот тебе для примера, можешь менять как тебе надо.

[image: вот тебе для примера]

В итоге получается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]