# Как сделать кнопку на Android с бордером снизу и справа?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть красная кнопка. Необходимо сделать бордер шириной 2dp снизу и справа + сделать изменение цвета кнопки во время нажатия на зеленый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Научился это делать с помощью сторонней библиотеки [BackgroundLibrary](https://github.com/JavaNoober/BackgroundLibrary). Но не понимаю как это сделать нативно с помощью drawable.

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        app:bl_unpressed_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:bl_pressed_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:bl_stroke_width="2dp"
        app:bl_stroke_color="#2196F3"
        app:bl_stroke_position="right|bottom"
        android:text="Button"/>
```

Платформа android, язык kotlin.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1063248/280456

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов, не вариант. Да и тот ответ как по мне не самый лучший. Лучше нарисовать shape и покласть его в state-list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте в папке `Drawable` файл `button_background_ripple.xml`:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="#9C1816"> // цвет заполнения при нажатии

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" /> // цвет в обычном состоянии
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="0dp" // обводка снизу как положено
    android:left="-20dp" // обводка слева выведена за края (не видно)
    android:right="0dp" // обводка справа как положено
    android:top="-20dp"> // обводка сверху выведена за края (не видно)
    <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp" // толщина обводки
            android:color="#0000FA" /> // цвет обводки
    </shape>
</item>
```

Затем устанавливаете на кнопку бэкграундом:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_background_ripple"
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное обьяснение. Сложно представить ответ лучше